Performance issue when reading a single partition Kafka topic with Spark
There is a Kafka topic with a single partition, created to ensure the order of messages. However, when attempting to read one million messages per window in Spark Streaming, the process is exceptionally slow.
Is there a way to improve performance without altering the topic's structure? I tried to repartition after dataframe read, but isn't work.
